# What is the last non-zero digit of $((\dots(((1!)!+2!)!+3!)!+\dots)!+1992!)!$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, integers, decimal-expansion

What is the last non-zero digit of $((\dots(((1!)!+2!)!+3!)!+\dots)!+1992!)!$?

---

Clarification of the given expression:

Let $A_1=(1!)!$

To get $A_2$, we add $2!$ to $A_1$ then we take the factorial of that expression. So, $A_2=((1!)!+2!)!$

To get $A_3$, we add $3!$ to $A_2$ then we take the factorial of that expression. So, $A_3=(((1!)!+2!)!+3!)!$

To get $A_4$, we add $4!$ to $A_3$ then we take the factorial of that expression. So, $A_4=((((1!)!+2!)!+3!)!+4!)!$

and so on.

---

Now we need to find the last non-zero digit of $A_{1992}$. I am not asking for a solution, but asking for some hints how shall I begin.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS.

Comment: Hint: what's the units digit of $5!$? of $6!$? of $7!$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you dear. But I have asked a wrong question. Could you please check my question now?

Comment: Dear??? I'd begin by computing a few examples to see whether there's a pattern. You might also look at the question listed under "Related", asking for the last non-zero digit of $50!$. There are two other Related questions asking about last nonzero digits involving factorials, they too might be helpful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I DO know how to find the last non-zero digit of $n!$. We have just find the floor(n/5)+floor(n/5^2)+floor(n/5^3)+... to infinity. But the expression in this post is different and I could not find any related problem.

Comment: That sum of floors that you have written has the same value, $1$, for $n=5,6,7,8,9$ but the last nonzero digit of $n!$ is $2,2,4,2,8$, so I don't understand what that formula does for you.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari You should add info like this to the question. Also you should add the solution for the last digits of $A_k$ for small $k$ to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ denote the last nonzero digit of $n!$; we need only consider $n\ge5$.

- Prove $a_n\in S:=\{2,\,4,\,6,\,8\}$.
- Prove $a_{10k+5}=a_{10k+14}$.
- Determine the order of the permutation $\sigma$ of $S$ for which $a_{10k+15}=\sigma(a_{10k+14})$.
- Find a fairly small upper bound $p$ on the period of $a_n$.
- Convince yourself $a_p,\,\cdots,\,a_{2p-1}$ is a period.
- Explain why the original problem's answer is $a_p$, then compute it.